# Trying to parse JSON data, but label not updating in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have some weather data that I'm downloading from Wunderground, and when I access the website the information comes back appropriately, but the label that I have that is supposed to change doesn't when this information is parsed. Here's the code...

```
let jsonResult: AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary

                if let city = jsonResult["current_observation"] as? NSDictionary {
                    if let weatherInfo = city["estimated"] as? NSDictionary{
                        if let  currentTemp = weatherInfo["feelslike_string"] as? NSString {


                            self.temperatureLabel.text = currentTemp
                        }
                    }
                }
```

And here's the JSON (Part of it):

```
{
    "current_observation" =     {
        UV = 0;
        "dewpoint_c" = 16;
        "dewpoint_f" = 60;
        "dewpoint_string" = "60 F (16 C)";
        "display_location" =         {
            city = "San Francisco";
            country = US;
            "country_iso3166" = US;
            elevation = "47.00000000";
            full = "San Francisco, CA";
            latitude = "37.77500916";
            longitude = "-122.41825867";
            magic = 1;
            state = CA;
            "state_name" = California;
            wmo = 99999;
            zip = 94101;
        };
        estimated =         {
        };
        "feelslike_c" = "16.4";
        "feelslike_f" = "61.5";
        "feelslike_string" = "61.5 F (16.4 C)";
        "forecast_url" = "http://www.wunderground.com/US/CA/San_Francisco.html";
        "heat_index_c" = NA;
        "heat_index_f" = NA;
        "heat_index_string" = NA;
        "history_url" = "http://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID=KCASANFR49";
        icon = cloudy;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.

Comment: Why would you expect to get the "feels_like" string out of "estimated" when there's nothing in "estimated"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `JSON` looks malformed.  `estimated` would be an empty dictionary, so this line:

```
if let currentTemp = weatherInfo["feelslike_string"] as? NSString
```

would not return `true` because `weatherInfo` would have no object for the key `"feelslike_string"`--it'd return `nil`.

---

The `"feelslike_string"` is a member of the `"current_observation"` dictionary and not the `"estimated"` dictionary.  The `"estimated"` dictionary in this JSON is empty and has no value for the key `"feelslike_string"`.

So we need to change our code to look like this:

```
if let currentObs = jsonResult["current_observation"] as? NSDictionary {
    if let currentTemp = currentObs["feelslike_string"] as? NSString {
        self.temperatureLabel.text = currentTemp
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm just learning how to do all of this, so how would I accomplish that?

Comment: As I said: *You need to move all of the key-value pairs within the braces.*  Where are you getting the JSON from?

Comment: As I mentioned in my original post, I'm getting it from Wunderground API

Comment: @PatrickBush See my most recent edit.